# Animation with KeyFrames goes wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewanimation

I'm playing a bit with animations.

I have a UIlabel i want to "fly" from the left side to the center, After im clicking a button.
The initial string of the label will be located at the center.

What i get is the label moving till the point of "origin" in the 3 seconds and then it "pops" in that position.

I want the UILabel to "slide"/animate to the target point in those 3 seconds - smoothly. The alpha property also doesn't seems to do the animation smooth.
Hope i made myself clear. Thank you.

```
    - (IBAction)showQuestionButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        // Step to the next question
        self.currentQuestionIndex++;

        // Am I pas the last question?
        if (self.currentQuestionIndex == [self.questions count]) {

            // Go back to the first question
            self.currentQuestionIndex = 0;
        }

        // Get the string at the index in the questions array
        NSString *question = self.questions[self.currentQuestionIndex];

        // Display the string in the question label
        self.questionLabel.text = question;

        // Reset the answer label
        self.answerLabel.text = @"???";
        self.questionLabel.alpha = 1.0;
// the animation animated a little bit after this point:
        CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0 - (self.questionLabel.frame.size.width/2.0), self.questionLabel.frame.origin.y);
        self.questionLabel.center = origin;


        [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:3.0 delay:0.0 options:0 animations:^{
            [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:3.0 animations:^{
                self.questionLabel.alpha = 1.0;
            }];
            [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:3.0 animations:^{
                self.questionLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.questionLabel.frame.origin.y) ;
            }];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            NSLog(@"finished animation");
        }];
    }
```

Comment: But that is not a keyframe animation, so why are you using a keyframe animation?

Comment: key frames animation are for CALayers use [UIView animationWith....]

Answer (score 1):

`relativeDuration` should be a number between 0 and 1. From the docs:

> The length of time over which to animate to the specified value. This
>   value must be in the range 0 to 1 and indicates the amount of time
>   relative to the overall animation length. If you specify a value of 0,
>   any properties you set in the animations block update immediately at
>   the specified start time. If you specify a nonzero value, the
>   properties animate over that amount of time. For example, for an
>   animation that is two seconds in duration, specifying a duration of
>   0.5 results in an animation duration of one second.

Furthermore, if you're using Auto Layout, you can't simply set the label's `center` property. You've got to adjust your constraints.